# Checkbox inside listview item change status

Tags: android, android-listview

Hi guys i have a simple listview and an extended baseadapter and i want to achieve the following functionality.

I have a simple layout for the list item: 1 checkbox and two listviews.

When an listitem is clicked(the whole layout, not just the checkbox) the checkbox status should change.

How can i achieve this functionality?

Here's what i do so far:

My adapter:

```
 package ro.gebs.captoom.adapters;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import ro.gebs.captoom.R;
import ro.gebs.captoom.datamodel.Mileage;
import ro.gebs.captoom.datamodel.Receipt;
import ro.gebs.captoom.interfaces.MileageReceiptInterface;
import ro.gebs.captoom.utils.fonts.CustomFontTextView;

/**
 * Created by Adrian on 9/19/13.
 */
public class SyncItemAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private ArrayList<MileageReceiptInterface> data;
    private Context context;

    public SyncItemAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<MileageReceiptInterface> data) {
        this.context = context;
        this.data = data;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    @Override
    public MileageReceiptInterface getItem(int position) {
        return data.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        final MileageReceiptInterface item = getItem(position);
        ViewHolder holder = null;

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            if (item != null) {
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                if (item.getMyType() == MileageReceiptInterface.I_AM_MILEAGE) {
                    convertView = li.inflate(R.layout.sync_mileage_item, parent, false);
                } else {
                    convertView = li.inflate(R.layout.sync_receipt_item, parent, false);
                }

                holder.clickMe = (LinearLayout) convertView;
                holder.itemDate = (CustomFontTextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.item_date);
                holder.itemStatus = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.item_status);
                holder.itemValue = (CustomFontTextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.value);

                convertView.setTag(holder);
            }

            final ViewHolder finalHolder = holder;
            holder.clickMe.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    finalHolder.itemStatus.toggle();
                }
            });

        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat();
        df.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);

        if (item != null) {
            if (item.getMyType() == MileageReceiptInterface.I_AM_MILEAGE) {
                final Mileage mileage = (Mileage) item;
                holder.itemDate.setText(mileage.getStartDate());
                holder.itemValue.setText(df.format(mileage.getDistance() * mileage.getPrice()) + " " + mileage.getCurrency());
            } else {
                final Receipt receipt = (Receipt) item;
                holder.itemDate.setText(receipt.getDate());
                holder.itemValue.setText(df.format(receipt.getValue()) + " " + receipt.getCurrency());
            }
        }


        return convertView;
    }

    private class ViewHolder {
        LinearLayout clickMe;
        CheckBox itemStatus;
        CustomFontTextView itemDate;
        CustomFontTextView itemValue;
    }


}
```

Here i link my adapter to my list:

```
    final MergeAdapter all_adapter = new MergeAdapter();

        ArrayList<Folder> folders = new FolderDataSource().selectAllFolders();
        for (Folder folder : folders) {
            final TreeMap<Long, ArrayList<MileageReceiptInterface>> sortedFolderItems = new ReceiptDataSource().loadUnsyncReceipts(folder.getId());
            if (!sortedFolderItems.isEmpty()) {
                final View header1 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.receipt_list_header, null);
                assert header1 != null;
                CustomFontTextView receipt_header_txt = (CustomFontTextView) header1.findViewById(R.id.receipt_header_txt);
                receipt_header_txt.setText(folder.getTitle());
                all_adapter.addView(header1);

                for (long receiptTimeStamp : sortedFolderItems.descendingKeySet()) {
                    SyncItemAdapter folder_stuff = new SyncItemAdapter(mContext, sortedFolderItems.get(receiptTimeStamp));
                    all_adapter.addAdapter(folder_stuff);
                }
            }
        }

        folder_list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "You clicked an item", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
```

However it seems that i can't catch the item clicked event properly as no toast appears when i click any item in the list...

any ideas?

**EDITED: SMALL CHANGES TO MY ADAPTER CLASS AND NOW IT WORKS JUST FINE**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add clickable = false, focusable = false on your checkbox in the xml. You should get the toast after clicking on the list item. In the onItemClick(...) method do view.findViewById(CheckboxId).toggle();

I didn't test it lately but it should work :)

Comment: thanks for the toogle tip, i updated my adapter class, i used something similar to what you proposed:)

Answer (score 0):

Add the following attribute to the root layout of your list item. This will block the events on your checkbox in the item:

```
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
```